# ¿Cómo ejecutar tareas en segundo plano con Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, alertdialog

Estoy haciendo una App para control de mantenimiento en el cuál tiene que hacer una serie de eventos a medida que el usuario vaya realizando su trabajo. Hasta aquí todo va perfecto, pero también me pidieron que cada una hora aparezca una alerta con el mensaje "¿Se encuentra disponible?" y el usuario confirme o rechace según corresponda.

El problema que tengo es que no sé como hacer que cada una hora me aparezca este mensaje y sinceramente no sé como puedo buscarlo para investigarlo ya que nunca hice algo parecido en el poco tiempo en el que estoy programando en Xamarin.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

PD: Aclaro por las dudas que este proyecto **no es de Xamarin.forms**.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar un Timer (System.Timers.Timer) para ejecutar algun metodo que necesites, te dejo un ejemplo

```
Timer aTimer = new Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += delegate
{
    // tu codigo
};
aTimer.Interval = 60000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
aTimer.AutoReset = true;
```

Y en el caso de que tengas que solicitarle alguna confirmacion al usuario, deberias hacerlo en el hilo de la UI, con RunOnUiThread.

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    // Codigo 
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! eso es lo que estoy haciendo para que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo... pero el problema surge cuando la App no está abierta, es decir que la hayan minimizado... en Xamarin.forms he usado Bound Services, pero en este caso no sé como debería hacerlo

Comment: intentaste hacer lo mismo? te dejo un ejemplo https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ApplicationFundamentals/ServiceSamples/BoundServiceDemo

Comment: Ahora estoy trabajando en otros proyectos, ni bien tenga la oportunidad voy a ver ese ejemplo y cualquier cosa te lo comento